# Windows Store App - Browser Control with script

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

We have a requirement to support the hosting of some third party HTML5 based UI in our Windows Store app.

The standard WebView control does not give us what we need. We need:

- To allow script to execute a callback in the XAML page and get a return
  value
- Call functions in the web page and get DOM objects back
- Get the document Ready event

We are going to need this in a UWP app too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To allow script to execute a callback in the XAML page and get a return value
>
> Call functions in the web page and get DOM objects back

The WebView has a `InvokeScriptAsync(String, IIterable)` method. You might be able to use this method with the JavaScript eval function to execute the specified script function from the currently loaded HTML, with specific arguments, and to use window.external.notify from the HTML event handler to notify the application using [WebView.ScriptNotify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Events) event.

> Get the document Ready event

You could choose the [DOMContentLoaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_DOMContentLoaded) and [NavigationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_NavigationCompleted) event.